# Solarized colors in vim don't seem to be working for me

Tags: mac, macos, vim, solarized

I am running vim, and trying to get the vim solarized colors to work in terminal.

I have this in my vimrc file:

```
set syntax on
set t_Co=256
" let g:solarized_termcolors=16
set background=light
colorscheme solarized
```

It doesn't seem to work.

I outputted (using :echo) the value of t_Co and it is 256.

What is the issue?  I'm confused.

Comment: why is the g:solarized_termcolors=16 line commented out?

Comment: because uncommenting it did not have any impact, its still all messed up, background is white, numbers on the left have a greyish background, and wherever there is text is greyish background.

Answer (score 8):

I had similar problems, adding this to my .vimrc fixed my problems

```
set term=xterm-256color
set background=light
colorscheme default
```

I'm not sure why setting the color scheme to default worked but I'm using solarized light as my terminal theme so maybe the colors are just similar to solarized, however they're good enough for me.

Comment: set term=xterm-256color was the way to go for me.

Comment: This is not setting the colorscheme to solarized.

Answer (score 4):

You need to do:

```
let g:solarized_termcolors=256
set background=light
colorscheme solarized
```

`let g:solarized_termcolors=256` enable degraded color mode. This is needed only if you do not apply solarized colors to your terminal emulator.

Comment: should I remove t_Co=256?   When I did what you put, my entire terminal was blinking every second or so....

Comment: Forcing the number of colors may work, but usually not. Set TERM environment variable to something appropiate for your emulator. What kind of terminal are you using?

Comment: I am on mac osx leapard, using the standard terminal.

Comment: Solarized's author explain how to setup Terminal.app properly [here](https://github.com/altercation/solarized/tree/master/osx-terminal.app-colors-solarized)

Answer (score 3):

Add to your `~/.vimrc`

```
" Solarized Dark
syntax enable
set t_Co=256
let g:solarized_termcolors=256
set background=dark
colorscheme solarized
```

This works on both ansi and xterm-256color versions of Solarized. Tested on Terminal 2.3 on a new OS X 10.8.5 VM installation.

*NB This answer supersedes the previous one that proposed changes to the profile swatches. I recently realised I had these commands in my `.vimrc` file that actually configured Solarized.*

Answer (score 3):

I have spent an 2-3 hours trying to figure it out. This is how to configure this color scheme with Vim.

Make sure you do not start **tmux** first. Sometimes it messes with the terminal color scheme.

1. `set syntax on`
2. `:echo &t_Co` in vim and see what you get. If it's 8 you'll want to `set t_Co=16` and if it's 256 than `set t_Co=256`
3. if you have set `t_Co=256` than next is `:let g:solarized_termcolors=256` or `t_Co=8` and `:let g:solarized_termcolors=16`
4. `set background=light` or `set background=black`
5. And finally `colorscheme solarized`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the default terminal, which do not support 256 colors. I installed [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/) and that solved the problem.

**Edit:**

Also, you need to install Solarized for iTerm2.

Comment: Thanks, I have been searching for this solution over a week but this works great.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

1. First, Download [solarized.vim](https://raw.github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized/master/colors/solarized.vim) to your .vim/colors folder
2. Next, Download [togglebg.vim](https://raw.github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized/master/autoload/togglebg.vim) to your .vim/autoload folder

Try to launch vim again & see if it works. If not, come back with error message

Comment: Tried that, and no change.  I do get this error but I think its unrelated (after I installed command-t) vim/bundle/vim-makegreen/plugin/makegreen.vim:
line   73:
E227: mapping already exists for \t